# java GridBagLayout not working?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use gridbagayout to align a jtabbedpane and a scrollpane. I tried to align them vertically. However, the result was horizontal. Does anyone why this happened? Thank you.

This is the actual result:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
  JTabbedPane tabs= new JTabbedPane();
  tabs.setOpaque(false);


        JScrollPane textScrollPane= new JScrollPane();
            textArea= new JTextArea();
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();
            caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
            textScrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        {
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.weightx=1;
            c.gridheight=4;
            panel.add(tabs,c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=1;
            c.weightx=1;
            c.gridheight=1;
            c.ipadx=20;
            c.ipady=10;
            panel.add(textScrollPane,c);

            /////restore to default
            c.gridheight=1;
            c.ipadx=0;
            c.ipady=0;
        }
```

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] when you ask a question so we don't have to guess about what your code is really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the result was horizontal. Does anyone why this happened?

Probably because the default layout manager of a JPanel is the `FlowLayout` and you didn't change the layout manager when you created the panel. The `FlowLayout` displays components horizontally.

When you create the panel you also need:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
```

Comment: Ahhhh... I made a stupid a stupid mistake by creating a GridLayout instead of GridBagLayout... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have another question... Is there any way to fix the ratios of the height of these two panels? I am hoping that they can be 4:1 no matter what the height of JFrame is.

Comment: If there is a way to set default size of these two panels, that will work too. But I heard people saying that you should never use "set...Size()" method because it will get ignored by gridBagLayout. Is that true?

Comment: Never mind. I found this https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/ and it works perfect! But still, thank you!